# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support MYSQL

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i made an application in VS 2010 that ran on MYSQL, the client would download this program and it would create its own MYSQL database. Now that i'm using VS 2013 i can't seem to get this to work again. Unless i included all these Dll files: [Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so my 3 questions are:

is it no longer supported?

is there a better local database type i could use instead, that doesn't require extra dll's?

will i have to send these dll's every time i update my application now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql was never supported natively by the .net framework, you must install the mysql conector to get full access to mysql  or you can use odbc but that's gonna be really slow.

If you want a compacto local db, then sqlite is much better for that Job.

And to send those dll's, it depends on how you do your update, if you have a system which remplaces your exe and leaves in place previous files, then it will work, but if you plan to use an installer, then the installer will have them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my experience with SQLlite is it seems to be slow when dealing with 100k rows compared to MYSQL

Comment: Of course, its an small local db, if you are dealign with those number of rows then stick with mysql or sql server.

Comment: part of the requirements of this application is that its a one off install, not to have to install a SQL server (they wouldn't know how to do this). so it sounds like i have to get MYSQL to work? thanks mate

Comment: also if it was never supported why did i not have to attach these Dll's before?

Comment: You did or you where using odbc, where you creating an OdbcConnection or a MySqlConnection in your code?

Comment: Take a look at this, its an alternative:http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh510202.aspx

Answer (score 1):

is it no longer supported?

```
It is supported I am using it in my project.
```

is there a better local database type i could use instead, that doesn't require extra dll's?

```
MSSQL if you want.(I am not sure about others)
```

will i have to send these dll's every time i update my application now?

```
No, you need to deploy only once unless you are panning to change MySQL connector. You only need to ship the "MySql.Data.dll" along with your project
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, MSSQL will need setting up of a server right?, can't create one from the application locally?

so you send the Dll files (in my link above) one time only?

Comment: Yes need to send dll only once